# Jquery week calendar change default view

Tags: jquery, calendar, jquery-week-calendar

I am using [jquery week calendar](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar) plugin and I need to change the default view as daily. Currently it is displaying weekly

```
 $calendar.weekCalendar({
displayOddEven: true,
        timeslotsPerHour: 4,
        allowCalEventOverlap: true,
        overlapEventsSeparate: true,
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        businessHours: {start: 8, end: 18, limitDisplay: false},
        daysToShow: 7,

        switchDisplay: {'daily': 1, 'weekly': 7},
});
```